# delay hover method

Tags: jquery, hover, delay

hi guys i would like to delay hover method in this function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".wypWedkarskie li").filter(":odd").hide().end().filter(":even").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("active")
      .next().stop(true, true).slideToggle();
  });
});
```

what i need to do ??

Comment: What do you mean by delay?  Not fire the hover unless the user stays over the element for a minimum amount of time or simply wait a little while before firing the callback, but still firing the callback if the user's mouse ever hovers even for an instant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to delay an action within a hover, you can use javascripts [`.setTimeout()`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) to add a delay of x seconds.

Try this, *it will hide all odd items in a list, then add a hover effect to all the even ones, upon hovering it will instantly toggle the active class, and after two seconds it will toggle the next object*:

```
$(".wypWedkarskie li").filter(":odd").hide().end().filter(":even").hover(
    function() {
        var obj = $(this);
        var nextObj = obj.next();

        obj.toggleClass("active");
        setTimeout(function() {
            nextObj.slideToggle();
        }, 2000);
    }
);
```

You can see a working [**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/fsCus/3/)

---

**Update :**

This should give you what I believe you are after. 
It will highlight the item you are hovering over instantly. After 2 seconds, if you are still hovering it will show the 2nd item. As soon as you stop hovering it will hide the 2nd item. If you stop hovering before 2 seconds, the 2nd item won't be shown:

```
$(".wypWedkarskie li").filter(":odd").hide().end().filter(":even").hover(
    function() {
        var obj = $(this);
        var nextObj = obj.next();
        obj.addClass("active");
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (obj.hasClass('active')) {
                nextObj.slideDown();
            }
        }, 2000);
    },
    function() {
        var obj = $(this);
        var nextObj = obj.next();
        obj.removeClass('active');
        nextObj.slideUp();
    }
);
```

See a working [**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/fsCus/5/)

Answer (score 2):

**Corrected code is below the horizontal rule**

Use jQuery's [`delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) function. This will wait a certain period of time before performing any methods called after it. For example:

```
$(this).delay(1000).toggleClass("active")
      .next().stop(true, true).slideToggle();
```

will wait for a delay of 1 second before toggling the `active` class, stopping the next sibling's animation, and so on.

---

Edit: Doh! I misunderstood jQuery's `delay`. You can use `setTimeout()`, then.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".wypWedkarskie li").filter(":odd").hide().end().filter(":even").hover(function () {
        el = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(el).toggleClass("active")
                .next().stop(true, true).slideToggle();
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/hans/Z4tqj/)

Comment: I think you are miss-understanding what [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) does. It does not delay chained methods, it adds a delay to [jQuery effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) which have been chained to an object. [Take a look here](http://jsfiddle.net/fsCus/1/) at a small demo for what delay does. Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry about that. I posted a corrected version of the code that uses setTimeout() instead.

Comment: i thought i want to do what you just write, but i dont, i would like to delay all function not just .hover part

Comment: You would like to delay all of the function? Can you explain more, please? Do you mean that you don't want to set up the hover effect until a certain time after the page has loaded?

Comment: i would like to triger this whole function after for example 5 sec after i mouseover a "li:even" element and triger it immediately when i mouseout "li:even" element, so that when i mouseover for 2 sec it wont triger at all

Comment: now it alweys triger even when i just mouseover for a half sec

Comment: but it waits whit that setTimeout time which is 1000 in yours example

Comment: Hmm.. you could add two events, one for `mouseenter` and one for `mouseleave`. In the `mouseenter` event, set some attribute of the HTML element, ex. `waiting` = `true`. Then set up a timeout to run the animation if that attribute still exists after a certain period of time. Then, in your `mouseleave` event, remove the attribute. Does that make sense? I'll write some example code if needed.

Comment: it make sense but i need help whit that

Comment: i have this $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".wypWedkarskie li").filter(":odd").hide().end().filter(":even").hover(
    function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("active")
      .next().stop(true, true).slideToggle();
});
}); which work perfect

Comment: and i would like to add those events to code above

Comment: where i have to add mouseenter and mouseleave events ??

Comment: gidzior see the update to my answer below for some help.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html). Is a plugin that tries to figure out if the user wants to put the mouse over an element, or if just passes the mouse over it.

Good luck!

Comment: i know this but i dont know how to combine it and hoverIntent it self work difrent

Comment: It doesn't work different. As you can see in plugin's demos, it replaces hover. You can use it in the same way you use hover. But it seems that you need something different. Why don't you explain what you want to do with more details?

Comment: i have a list 

<li><a href="#"><img src="img/flagaSzwecja.png" />SZWECJA</a></li>

<li class="zdjecie"><img src="img/zdjSzwecja.jpg" /></li>

<li><a href="#"><img src="img/flagaNorwegia.png" />NORWEGIA</a></li>

<li class="zdjecie"><img src="img/zdjSzwecja.jpg" /></li>


and i want to show/hide <li class="zdjecie"></li> when mouseover/mouseout <li><a href="#"></a></li> element

Comment: sory for formating i dont know how to break the lines LOL